# How to transform this plot in a right subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science, visualization

I have to plot this by subplots, I have 4 features and i want to have 2 rows and 2 columns, how can i do that?

```
cat_features = ['Gender', 'Customer Type', 'Type of Travel', 'Class', 'satisfaction']

f, axs = plt.subplots(2, len(cat_features[:-1]), figsize=(10, 4))
for ax, col in zip(axs, cat_features[:-1]):
    sns.countplot(data=df_train, x=col, hue="satisfaction",palette='Blues',ax=ax.flatten()[i])
f.tight_layout()
```

This is the result but it's so bad
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a _small_ sample input data and the corresponding expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, starting with a **minimal reproducible example** (made up data). In this example, we also show a technique to remove empty plots in the case your number of plots don't neatly fit in an n x m grid.

##### 1. Synthetic sample data

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

from itertools import zip_longest

n = 100
np.random.seed(0)
df_train = pd.DataFrame({
    'Gender': np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female'], n),
    'Customer Type': np.random.choice(['Loyal', 'Occasional'], n),
    'Type of Travel': np.random.choice(['Plane', 'Train', 'Cruise'], n),
    'Class': np.random.choice(['First', 'Business', 'Economy'], n),
    'satisfaction': np.random.choice(['neutral or dissatisfied', 'satisfied'], n),
})
```

##### 2. Plot

```py
cat_features = ['Gender', 'Customer Type', 'Type of Travel', 'Class', 'satisfaction']

hue = 'satisfaction'
others = [k for k in cat_features if k != hue]
ncols = 2
nrows = int(np.ceil(len(others) / ncols))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(4*ncols, 3*nrows))
for ax, col in zip_longest(axes.ravel(), others):
    if col is None:
        fig.delaxes(ax)
    else:
        sns.countplot(data=df_train, x=col, hue=hue, palette='Blues', ax=ax)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Why using `zip_longest`? Say the number of plots doesn't divide envenly into your desired number of columns. For purpose of illustration, let's say we used `ncols=3` above:

[image]