# pyplot: create subplots by looping - axs[i] interpreted as tuple?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to create subplots depicting the frequencies of random values from a normal distribution.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,1, sharex = True)
i = 0

axs = axs.ravel()
for n in [100, 1000, 10000]:
    random_variables = scipy.stats.norm.rvs(loc=10, scale=3, size=n)   
    axs[i] = plt.hist(random_variables)
    axs[i].set_ylabel('number of occurrences of this value')
    i += 1
axs.set_xlabel('value of random sample')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

For `axs[i].set_ylabel('number of occurrences of this value')` I get `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_ylabel'` and I'm also very confused since (I think) all iterations get plottet into the third histogram. Why is `axs[i]` interpreted as a tuple? I thought by `axs.ravel()` would make it possible to iterate but obviously I was wrong. Could you give me a tip please?

Answer (score 0):

An idiom I often use is:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, sharex=True)
for ax, n in zip(axes.ravel(), [100, 1000, 10000]):
    ...
```

Sometimes, when the number of plots doesn't fit a nice `nrows * ncols` grid, I like to use `zip_longest()` and `fig.delaxes(ax)` to eliminate the empty plots, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74888998/758174).